# PHP: php.ini include_path after changing doesn't work Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, include-path

Hi I have tryed to install zend framerwork on Ubuntu 14.04.

in installing steps I have changed

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

file where I replace

```
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
```

TO

```
include_path = ".:/home/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library"
```

After than my other php project stoped working.

I got this Error

```
Warning: require_once(view/display/home .php): 
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
 in /var/www/html/helix/view/View.php on line 33


Fatal error: require_once(): 
 Failed opening required 'view/display/home .php' 
  (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear/') 
   in /var/www/html/helix/view/View.php on line 33
```

Please Help me

Comment: You may need to restart Apache after modifying php.ini.

Comment: But you want to _append_ to the include_path, not replace it:  `include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/home/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library"` By replacing it your removed `/usr/share/php` which may have been the location of previously needed files.

Comment: As the previous include_path line was commented out, I guess that somewhere else there is an other include_path set (as output doesn't even fit to the "old" value)

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your php process, or in your case, likely apache -

`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

In other cases, it could be :

`$ sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Or I've even seen

`$sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: My favorite is: $> sudo apache2ctl graceful

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, it seams that you have a typo, you try to include a file named:

```
view/display/home .php
```

where it should probably read:

```
view/display/home.php
```

without the extra space... between home and .php

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache error logs to see if you have another error in your php.ini file. I had an error somewhere else, and apache was pretty much ignoring my ini file after encountering the error.